# What's the point of "for x in y" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, idioms

I'm learning Ruby and RoR at the moment, and I came across this:

```
<% for post in @posts %>
```

in the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). I'd understood that the idiomatic way to do this in Ruby is with:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

If there is a difference then what is it? And if there isn't a difference then wouldn't it be better for the Rails people to be pushing proper Ruby idioms (rather than this, which looks more pythonic to me)?

**Edit:** I've just found two conflicting explanations of this: [Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm) says they're the same except "a for loop doesn't create a new scope for local variables", whereas [CS.Auckland.ac.NZ](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/ruby/doc_bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#for) says `for` is just syntactic sugar for the equivalent `.each`.

**Edit2:** The `for ... in` in question was for the `index.html.erb` generated in `app/views/posts` by `script/generate scaffold`. I've done a quick check and that now generates the `.each` syntax. I guess that part of the guide was written at an earlier stage of rails development when the scaffold generated `for ... in`.

**Edit3:** I can now confirm that `for x in y` was used in Rails 2.2.2, but by 2.3.8 it is using `y.each do |x|`. Just so you know.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The tutorialpoint page is correct, `for` is equivalent to `each` except for the scoping difference. Here's a demonstration:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
arr.each do |x|
  last = x
end
last # NameError
```

vs.

```
arr = [1,2,3]
for x in arr
  last = x
end
last #=> 3
```

If you want to make it work using `each`, you need to do `last = nil` before the loop. This is, as the link pointed out, because blocks start a new scope while `for` does not.

Note however that this rarely makes a practical difference and few people are even aware of it.

When people use `for` in ruby it's most often because that's what they're used to coming from other languages - not because of any differences between `for` and `each`.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. This takes me back to my original point though, which is why would the Rails team (or at least whoever wrote the Getting Started guide) go with the `for ... in` syntax?

Comment: There's a lot of people who learn rails without having learned ruby first. I suppose the guide is written in a style that's intended to look familiar to people coming from other languages.

Comment: A related difference between the two that isn't obvious just from that example: `a=[]; for x in [1,2,3,4]; a << proc {x} end; map(&:call)` gives `[4,4,4,4]` while the equivalent with `each` would give `[1,2,3,4]` because `each` introduces a new `x` binding with each iteration.

Comment: Performance wise I would imagine `for x in arr` is a tad faster, not that it matters that much

Comment: There are differences between those constructions, but I doubt if it was real reason for introducing both of them.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the first example (`for post in @posts`) looks more "procedural", while the second (`@posts.each do |post|`) looks more "functional".  Unfortunately, procedural way to read code is still considered more popular, more clear and less "geeky".  That's why, perhaps, many would prefer it to the "native" way of iterating through containers.

If it looks pythonic (I'm not sure if it's true), then it may be considered even better, since it improves accessibility of Rails by developers that come from other platforms.

Personally, I'd like ruby and "functional" ways to be pushed.  But the above reasons demonstrate that it can be done either way.

Comment: I say it looks pythonic because `for ... in` is the standard way to iterate in Python.

Comment: @skill, as well as it's a standard way of iterating in other languages (obsolete Perl syntax, for example).  It also is the *natural* (in the sense how humans thing about it) way of iterating through any collection.

Comment: yes, I see what you mean. I wasn't necessarily saying that they were copying Python, just that it looks more like Python.

Answer (score 0):

Some day I was developing the feature of generating PDF reports for the website I was working on.

The plugin I was using had many limitations. Those limitations enforced me to produce the solution which was very imperative and procedural. I was using constructions like `while` or `for` just to emphasis this style of programming.

In fact, this was the only situation when I used those keywords in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `for x in y` if you're trying to do ruby profiling and your version of ruby-prof doesn't have [method elimination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241491/is-it-possible-to-ignore-irrelevant-methods-when-profiling-ruby-applications).

Answer (score 0):

One more thing about `for x in y` is that you can do `for i in 1..5` which will work like a standard for loop, starting at `i = 1` and going through `i = 5`.

The handy thing about this is that you can use a range like `3..8` or `x..y`, you are not stuck starting from zero, which you would be by using `n.times`  method.

Comment: Wouldn't 1.upto(5).each {|x| #something} take care of that?

Comment: @jeba ya it would. I'm relatively new to ruby, so I hadn't seen that before. So thank you! I learn something new every day!

Comment: You can also do `(1..5).each`